# cd into directories with a specific pattern, read file content and print their content to a text file in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to automate a report generation process.

I need to enter into directories having a specific pattern and then read files from them. The directories name is in pattern PYYYYMMDD001, PYYYYMMDD002 and so on. I need to enter each directory with the defined pattern and read data from each file within the directory. But I am unable to do so as I am committing a mistake while defining the pattern. Please find the command I am using

```
TODAY=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
cd /home/user/allFiles
for d in "P"$TODAY*
do
(cd $d && grep -o '-NEW' *_$TODAY*_GOOD* | uniq -c| sed 's/\|/ /'|awk '{print $1}' > /home/user/new/$TODAY"Report.txt" )
done
```

When I am trying to execute it, getting the error of P02192017* [No such file or directory]

The list of directories are - P02192017001, P02192017002, P02192017003 , P02192017004 , P02192017005, P02192017006 , P02192017007, P02192017008

Any kind of help towards this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the *exact* output you get with `bash -x yourscript`.

Comment: Also post result of `ls` in `/home/user/allFiles`

Comment: Also unrelated but `%m%d%Y` is an awful date format.

Comment: The error I got is

-ksh[3]: cd: P02192017: [No such file or directory]

ls in /home/user/allFiles displays directories:

P02192017001, P02192017002, P02192017003, P02192017004, P02192017005, P02192017006, P02192017007, P02192017008

. Actually report is to be generated as per current date and the directories name is having current date in them, that is why I was referring that pattern. Thanks

Comment: How are you running this file? Are you even using bash?

Comment: Yes I am trying with bash

Comment: @123 , got the output as per bash -x script.sh


$ bash -x raw.sh
++ date +%m%d%Y
+ TODAY=02192017
+ cd /mapr/datalake/uhc/ei/pi_ara/projects/837_B2B/newprocess/processing/allFile                                                                                                             s/
+ for d in '"P"$TODAY*'
+ cd 'P02192017*'
raw.sh: line 7: cd: P02192017*: No such file or directory

Comment: By the way,  you CANNOT pass unsorted input to `uniq`.

Comment: @mohit Post previous comment formatted into the question

Comment: "yes I am trying with bash" but your error message says "-ksh[3]". Do  you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script?  Also (should matter), but try `for d in P${TODAY}*` ... Good luck.

Comment: AND if you have any control of your report date format, please use `%Y%m%d` This format will automatically sort, so you can use `ls -lt | head -1` to the the newest file, and `ls -lt | tail -1` to get the oldest file (just for example). Good luck.

Comment: Never used bash, but in csh I'd write the loop as `foreach f (\`find -print -name "P*$TODAY*"\`)`. Try to see if this syntax works in bash as well.

Comment: @123, I got this when I ran bash - x file.sh

`++ date +%m%d%Y + TODAY=02192017 + cd /mapr/datalake/uhc/ei/pi_ara/projects/837_B2B/newprocess/pro‌​cessing/allFile s/ + for d in '"P"$TODAY*' + cd 'P02192017*' raw.sh: line 7: cd: P02192017*`

Comment: @shelter, yes I corrected that and still, it shows the error I have posted above. As per your advice, I made the changes and still got the same error on that.

Comment: @user2141046, the syntax didn't work. :(

Comment: Seems like it should work. Please edit your Q with output of `ls -l P*` . Good luck.

Comment: AND, if you have used MS Windows to create or transport your script, use `cat -vet scriptName`. If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, use `dos2unix scriptName`. Good luck.